# Why am I getting an error in this mathematical formula?

Tags: math-mode, errors, editors

I used the [Daum Equation Editor](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/daum-equation-editor/id540665783?mt=12) to create the following formula:

[image]

This was the generated Tex:

```
{ f }_{ LR\_ FI }\left( x \right) =\left\{ 
L\left( \frac { { m }_{ l }-x }{ \alpha  }  \right) ,x\le { m }_{ l },\\ 
1,{ m }_{ l }\le x\le { m }_{ r },\\ 
R\left( \frac { x-{ m }_{ r } }{ \beta  }  \right) ,x\ge m \right
```

In the Latex editor however, I get the following error:

```
Missing delimiter (. inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   $
l.1288 ...} }{ \beta  }  \right) ,x\ge m \right \]
```

provided that the Tex in in math mode.

Why am I getting this error, and how can I get it solved?

Thanks.

Comment: it would be a lot easier for people to help you if you provided an example that could be run to produce the error. presumably you have more `\left` than `\right` (but most of the `\left` and `\right` are incorrect and should be deleted `\left( x \right) ` is wrong and should be `(x)`

Comment: oh, your final `\right` is missing a  `.`  it should be `\right .`  (but it would be better to use a `cases` environment)

Comment: @Simplicity Why use you Daum Equation Editor? You could try https://www.latex4technics.com/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I had to have a "." after the last \right. The issue is that I have all the lines beside each other rather on new lines. Any ideas why is that? Thanks.

Comment: if you want someone to comment on the output, provide an example that produces some output not a fragment that leaves everyone to guess in what context it has been used.  Please edit your example as requested in the first comment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The context is actually a formula I generated using a tool and pasted in the Latex editor :-) Any more information to provide?

Comment: all the "lines" are on the same line because a multiline expression needs to be indicated as an environment that defines multiple lines.  just inserting `\\ ` isn't enough.  `cases` from `amsmath` is one such environment.

Comment: Yes you should provide a complete test document that produces the error (see Bernard's answer) otherwise you make people guess what you did wrong, did you not put the fragment in a math enviornment?, did you not include some needed package? etc and make everyone have to invent and type out a required preamble. (Or more likely they  do not do that and so you do not get an answer, although Bernard answered this time) In this case the issue about line breaking is precisely because of code you have not shown. If we guess that you put the fragment in an environment where `\\ ` does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The final `\right` was missing a `.`. But anyway, one can obtain a nicer result.

Here are three ways to obtain such a nicer result, with a lighter code, based either on the `dcases`environment from `mathtools` or on `alignat` and package `empheq` (which loads `mathtools`), combined with package `eqparbox` for a nicer alignment (due to the length difference of the middle row w..r.t. the upper and lower rows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}

\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath, empheq}
\usepackage{eqparbox} 
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle #2$}}

\begin{document} %

\[ f_{ LR\_ FI }(x ) = \begin{dcases}
\eqmathbox{L\Bigl( \frac {m_{l}-x }{\alpha} \Bigr),} & x \le m_{ l }, \\
\eqmathbox{1,} & m_{l} \le x \le m_{r},\\
\eqmathbox{R\Bigl( \frac{x - m_{r}}{\beta}\Bigr),} & x \ge m_{r}. 
\end{dcases} \]%

\[ f_{ LR\_ FI }(x ) = \begin{dcases}
\eqmathbox{ L\Bigl( \frac {m_{l}-x }{\alpha} \Bigr),} & \eqmathbox[C]{x \le m_{ l },} \\
\eqmathbox{1,} & \eqmathbox[C]{ m_{l} \le x \le m_{r},}\\
\eqmathbox{R\Bigl( \frac{x - m_{r}}{\beta}\Bigr),} & \eqmathbox[C]{x \ge m_{r}.} 
\end{dcases} \]%

\begin{empheq}[left={f_{ LR\_ FI }(x ) = \empheqlbrace}]{alignat* = 2}
 & \eqmathbox{ L\Bigl( \frac {m_{l}-x }{\alpha} \Bigr),} &\quad x & \le m_{ l }, \\
 & \eqmathbox{1,} & m_{l} & \le x \le m_{r},\\
 & \eqmathbox{R\Bigl( \frac{x - m_{r}}{\beta}\Bigr),} & x & \ge m_{r}. 
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions:

- Don't overuse `\left` and `right` to auto-size parentheses -- quite often, it's better to impose a fixed size
- Don't needlessly use curly braces to encase various items -- overuse of `{`and `}` makes the code harder, not easier, to read
- Encase the string `LR\_FI` in a `\mathit` (or `\mathrm`, if you prefer) statement, for a more compact "look"
- For a more-compact appearance, consider using inline-fraction notation instead of `\frac{...}{...}`
- Do familiarize yourself with the `amsmath` package and its `cases` environment as well as the `mathtools` package (a superset of the `amsmath` package) and its `cases*` environment

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'cases*' environment
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional -- Times Roman clone
\begin{document}
\[
f_{\mathit{LR\_FI}}^{}(x) =
\begin{cases*}
L((m_l-x)/\alpha) & if $x\le m_l$\,, \\
1                 & if $m_l\le x\le m_r$\,, \\
R((x-m_r)/\beta)  & if $x\ge m$\,.
\end{cases*}
\]
\end{document}
```